# gnuplot history graph with repeating data

Tags: gnuplot

I have this data:

```
0 0.105773
1 -0.062457
2 0.005387
3 -0.000000
4 -0.000000
5 0.000000
6 0.000000
7 0.000000
0 0.116266
1 -0.129877
2 0.004714
3 -0.000000
4 -0.000000
5 0.000000
6 0.000000
7 0.000000
```

Each different value in the first column is supposed to be a line in the graph, so the graph will have 8 lines. I need a history graph, where each time this 8 numbers repeat it will represent an increment on X axis and the values on the second column a point in the Y axis for it time.

Is there a way to do this with gnuplot? I have no idea how to make it interpret the data in the way the log is.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're actually looking for here.  in your example, you say that you want to plot 8 lines.  What points compose those lines?  E.g. is the first line composed of the points `[(1,0.105773),(2,0.116266)]`?  (both have 0 in the first column)

Comment: The first line is composed by all the lines that start with 0, in this example it would be [(0, 0.105773), (0, 0.116266)] then the second line would be all the lines that start with the number 1: [(1, -0.062457), (1, -0.129877)] and this way on. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you're plotting vertical lines?

Comment: Yes, each time a number repeats it will increment one value on axis X, and the float value the log file has will be plot in axis Y.

Comment: Also, in the example I posted it would be a 8 lines graph, but the log file can contain more or less lines to be plotted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to beat the data into a format that gnuplot likes.  I like to use python, here's a script which should do the trick:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

fname = sys.argv[1]
with open(fname) as fin:
    data = defaultdict(list)  
    for line in fin:
        x,y = line.split()
        data[int(x)].append(float(y))

for k,v in sorted(data.items()):
    for i,elem in enumerate(v):
        print i,elem
    print
    print
```

You could plot that datafile like this:

```
plot '<python pythonscript.py data.dat' u 1:2:(column(-2)) w lines lc variable lw 3
```

Or if you need to adjust the data in the legend slightly:

```
plot for [i=0:10] '<python pythonscript.py test.dat' index i u 1:2 w lines lw 3 title sprintf('Geophone %d',i)
```

where `10` is just a number sufficiently big enough :-).

Comment: It's generating vertical lines: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/600/77994098.png/

Comment: I changed the log file to the following format (http://pastebin.com/ykcVsauT): <line_number> <x_axis_value> <y_axis_value> then used grep to put each line_number in a different log file and then used this script (http://pastebin.com/Yx3Er7AT) to plot the way I want it (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/81791416.png/). Is there a way to merge this effort with your solution? I apologize if the information I gave wasn't enough. I'm pretty sure there is a easy way to get the graph I need with your solution.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong -- It seems like you have a working solution -- Is there any reason for you to change it?  Sorry that I misunderstood your original post (I thought you wanted vertical lines).  It would be trivial to adjust using the original data file + python as in my second example if you want me to post that, let me know.

Comment: Yes I have a working solution, but your solution is more elegant than mine, which means I prefer yours. Do you mind posting that using gnuplot script?

Comment: @FredericoSchardong -- Now that I understand what you need, I think I've written a quick python+gnuplot combination that will do the job for you.

Comment: File "graph2.py", line 9, in <module>
    d[int(x)].append(float(y))
NameError: name 'd' is not defined

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything about python

Comment: @FredericoSchardong - Sorry, that's my fault.  I found that when debugging locally, but forgot to make the change on my post.  It should be `data`, not `d`.  (the problem was in 2 places). -- I copied my working code here directly, so hopefully it should be OK now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20896/discussion-between-frederico-schardong-and-mgilson)